How can the Holy Spirit be a separate entity from the Father if the Father's own spirit dwells within us?
John 14:10 ESV

Do you not believe that I am in the Father, and the Father is in
Me? The words that I speak to you I do not speak on My own
authority; but the Father who dwells in Me does the works.

Matthew 12:28 ESV

Jesus said, "But if it is by the Spirit of God that I cast out demons,
then the kingdom of God has come upon you."

Ezekiel 36:27 ESV

And I will put My Spirit within you and cause you to walk in My
statutes and to carefully observe My ordinances.

Matthew 10:20 ESV

For it will not be you speaking, but the Spirit of your Father
speaking through you.

1 Corinthians 2:10-11 ESV

But God has revealed it to us by his Spirit. The Spirit searches all
things, even the deep things of God. For who among men knows the
thoughts of man except his own spirit within him? So too, no one knows
the thoughts of God except the Spirit of God.

How can the Holy Spirit be a separate person from God the Father's spirit? Wouldn't that split the Father God from his own spirit which he pours out onto us?

"how can the Holy Spirit be a separate person from God the Father's spirit?" This does not sound like the teachings of any Christian group I've ever heard of. Can you please [edit] to clarify what exactly you're asking about here. Also, this seems like a theology question that probably belongs on Christianity.se.

@curiousdannii – I just clarified my question.

@curiousdannii, his question is perfectly understandable since Bible Trinitarians teach that the Father is not the Holy Spirit but both are God, then his question follows.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany But Trinitarians don't teach that the Holy Spirit is a separate person from God the Father's spirit! In any case this is definitely systematic theology.

@curiousdannii, check the answer below. It explains why some Christiand believe the Holy Spirit is a separate entity from the Father

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Yes, all Trinitarians believe the Holy Spirit is a different person from the Father. What they don't believe is that the Holy Spirit is a separate person from the Father's Spirit.

@curiousdannii, sure because they share the same divine essence.

Here are 3 directions to be considered:

There is distinction between God the Father and the Holy Spirit.
The Holy Spirit is simply another description of the Father.
The Holy Spirit is a creative force from the Father.

We want to know whether the Bible depicts the Holy Spirit as merely an extension of the Father.
Are they distinct?

Matthew 28:19 - Go, therefore, and make disciples of all the nations,
baptizing them in the name of the Father and the Son and the Holy
Spirit,

What we see here is that they are mentioned individually separated by the use of "and" or "καὶ" in the Greek. Yet, they appear unified in the single act of baptism.

2 Corinthians 13:14 - The grace of the Lord Jesus Christ, and the love
of God, and the fellowship of the Holy Spirit, be with you all.

Again the Holy Spirit is also listed as distinct from the Father and the Son.

John 14:26 - But the Helper, the Holy Spirit whom the Father
will send in My name, He will teach you all things, and remind you
of all that I said to you.

The Father sends the Holy Spirit. The Holy Spirit does not send Himself and the Father doesn't send the Father. What we see then is that the Holy Spirit appears to be described as having a specific but distinct role: To teach believers all things and remind them of the words of Jesus.


Romans 8:27 - and He who searches the hearts knows what the mind of
the Spirit is, because He intercedes for the saints according to the
will of God.

Here's what we see here:
Argument:

Individuals who carry out tasks for others are typically recognized
as distinct persons. Take for example, an employee following a
manager's instruction.
In this same way, the Holy Spirit performs specific tasks under the
direction of the Father.
Based on the observed pattern, we may infer that the Holy Spirit is a
distinct person because He consistently acts in accordance with the
Father's will.

My conclusion the is that option 1, that there is a distinction between God the Father and the Holy Spirit, provides a coherent interpretation of the data and is scripturally supported.

I stand by option 2. It is clear that God the Father has a universal Spirit that is sent out in Jesus name to unite the elect saints with the Father's mindset. The gifts of the Spirit are the powers of God the Father.

Jason, Matthew 28:19 as we know it is spurious; Eusebius had a copy of Matthew which he quoted from nearly a dozen times that read, "in my name", without the Trinitarian formula. This dovetails with baptizing in Jesus' name only as found in the book of Acts, as well as the "in his name" found in Luke.

Alternative views are more than welcome! I've only provided a view which I find scripturally sound. For the sake of the question you might have to expand upon what you mean by "the Father has a universal Spirit".

As for Eusebius' account, that has been debated here as well. The fact remains that there is no evidence supporting the existence of an alternative version of Matthew 28:19 in any of the manuscripts available to us. Plus, for the shorter reading hypothesis to hold true, it would have required the systematic destruction of every manuscript containing the "original" version of Matthew 28:19, followed by the replacement of these texts with new manuscripts featuring the longer reading. Such a conspiracy would demand a level of control that was simply not feasible during that historical period.
